# Missing image on Bootstrap 4 Modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal

My success image is not displaying on Bootstrap 4 Modal. How to fixed it? I have check the source folder is correct.

Is there have an alternative way to displaying image on Modal?

I have tried below methods but not working, clear cache and hard reload page.

1) `<img src="../images/content_success.png">`

2) `<img src="./images/content_success.png">`

3) `<img src="/images/content_success.png">`

[image]

**Console.log**

```
GET http://localhost/daffodil-ui/images/content_success.png 404 (Not Found)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="success-upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center font-18">
                <h3 class="mb-20">File Uploaded!</h3>
                <div class="mb-30 text-center"><img src="/images/content_success.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please show the console

Comment: also its better if you could update the question with the full code

Comment: just update console log, what code do you want? I thought that is sufficient.

Comment: ok console says that it cant find the file. So the error is clear. You have to define the path correctly.Show us your folder structure to post a answer

Comment: Ok, now i already get the path after seeing console.log. thanks anyway.

Comment: I thought that "../images" is able to find path automatically, does not matter how many folder I have.

Comment: Just ask if you need any help. Answering questions can improve my votes. So feel free if you need any help